# Captions visible in web browser but not in mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile

I'm adapting a template, and can't make it work. The photo caption appears in browser but not in mobile. Is it missing a code or should I modify it. Don't know either if the CSS code is the right for that class=

Thanks in advance for the help!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzg3k.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjhE7.jpg

HTML

```css
.portfolio-overlay {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.portfolio-overlay .caption {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0 30px;
  text-align: left;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div data-groups="[&quot;people&quot;]" class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 no-pad">
  <div class="portfolio-item">
    <a href="../media/galeria/bonito-bodoquena/1.jpg" title="Test 1" class="swipebox"><img src="../media/galeria/bonito-bodoquena/1.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="portfolio-overlay">
        <div class="caption">
          <h5>Test 1</h5><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
```

Comment: What happens if you change `bottom` to `top` for the caption CSS? Since we can't see your entire code, the portfolio overlay may be overflowing the mobile screen port.

Comment: `opacity: 0;  visibility: hidden;` on `.portfolio-overlay` hides it.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, but those modifications applies on the gallery itself, not when I select one image and goes to full screen. BTW in the browser it appear ok, the problem is in mobile as the picture attached.